# How to update entity display names

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In our Dynamics CRM online instance, we've got the `Notes` entity:

[image: Notes entity]

which allows file uploads:

[image: Notes allow file uploads]

We're able to change the label using Form Editor

[image: Change label in Form Editor]

We just need to update the label **NOTES** above the text box and **No Notes found.** below the text box.

Instead it should be **DOCUMENTS** and **No Documents found**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a solution and add the Notes entity to it.

Then, Click on the Export Translations button in the solution.

Open the exported file and Update the translation text of *Note* and *Notes*.

Save the file and re import the translations file.

This will change the text in all the forms of your organization, not only the form you are customizing.

If you want to change the text in only one form, the only way I see is use an **unsupported** Javascript to find the html element containing the text and change its values.

More Info: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/export-customized-entity-and-field-text-for-translation.aspx